# Output custom taxonomy name on single post page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Googled this but cannot find an answer.

I have created a custom taxonomy for posts.

I want to list the taxonomy assigned to a post on the single post page. For example when i want to list a posts Tags or Categories I would do this:

```
<?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>

<?php the_category(', ') ?>
```

How can I list a custom taxonomy on a single post page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy_name', 'myTaxonomy: ', ', ', '<br />' );
```

or

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name', 'myTaxonomy: ', ', ', '<br />' );
```

should do the trick.